# Calling erase() on set during iteration

Tags: c++, loops, segmentation-fault, set, mingw

I have the following code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<string> S;
    S.insert("item1");
    S.insert("item2");
    S.insert("item3");
    S.insert("item4");
    int i=0;
    for (set<string>::iterator it = S.begin(); it != S.end(); it++)
        {
            string temp = *it;
            if (i++%2)
            {
                S.erase(temp); // Causes Seg Fault on next iteration
            }
        }
    cout<<"Items Removed\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The above code tries to remove elements from the set based on a trivial condition. It fails on my system when compiled with mingw-w64 (gcc 7.1.0 x86_64-posix-seh-rev0) with a segmentation fault.

Now I assumed this was because `erase()` invalidates the iterator to the current element, thus causing `it++` to fail. But I'm confused why this works fine on all the online IDEs I've tried ([Repl.it](http://repl.it/), [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/), [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/ide), [Coilru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), [Cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/)). Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've realized, [std::set::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) will invalidate the iterators to the erased element. Then the code leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), that means anything is possible but nothing is guaranteed; even though it seems working well but you can't rely on it at all.

Comment: So it's just a coincidence that the code works on so many different online IDEs?

Comment: @Erric Yes, that's what UB means.

Comment: I was familiar with the behaviour, but just saw this code online and it was working on their IDE, but not mine and I needed confirmation. Thanks